# How to play games in widescreen in Windows 7, Dell Studio 1555

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

I have a dell studio 1555 laptop with a GPU inside. The details are below;

**Hardware details**
[image]

**Software details**
[image]

I can play games in widescreen in Vista, but not in 7. I am using Windows 7 Home Premium. I have the latest Catalyst Control Center. Instead of widescreen, the games are running in a classic style, say like 1024x768 ratio. I have a screen resolution of 1366x768. I have no problem with HD videos and anything else.

The expected result is this;

[image]

And what I get is this;

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: why -1??  i have a genuine question..

Comment: Which "Need for Speed" game are you trying to play and under which resolution? Also did that game worked at Vista with the resolution you are trying?

Comment: i play nfs underground..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Need For Speed Underground don't have widescreen support. There is a patch for it [here](http://www.wsgf.org/dr/need-speed-underground-2).

Comment: i got it, but the same happens for all other games including NFS most anted

Comment: "Need for Speed: Most Wanted" doesn't support widescreen either, a quick search at the [Wide Screen Gaming Forum](http://www.wsgf.org), the site I linked earlier, will show you that there is a [patch](http://www.wsgf.org/dr/need-speed-most-wanted) for it too.

Answer (score 0):

You will, most likely, have to change the aspect ratio inside each game's video settings to 16:9, which is what I understand your screen supports, and then you will be able to set the resolution to a widescreen resolution like 1366 x 768.

**Note:** If you don't have any problems with video playback, then most likely your video adapter driver already supports 16 : 9 aspect ratio, you just have to enable it in the software you want to use it with.